# RDP connection allows any domain name as long as user is correct

Tags: remote-desktop, domain-controller, remote-access

I'm hoping someone can provide some ideas about this.

I've got a couple of virtual Windows servers set up on Server 2016 and Server 2019. They are DCs and also RDS servers to run remote apps.

I'm encountering a curious situation where, in both instances, when I connect to the servers either via remote app or directly via IP/port using Microsoft Remote Desktop, I am prompted to enter credentials as expected, however the domain does not appear to matter. As an example, if the correct domain is CORRECTDOMAIN and the user is USER1, the following credentials work:

CORRECTDOMAIN\USER1

However, the following also works:

PICKLE\USER1

Of note, a domain user is required to login. If I try with an incorrect user, it does not allow me to log in. Essentially any domain string appears to be accepted.

I'm connecting from Windows 10 machines from various IP addresses/networks not in the same domain as the RDS/DCs.

Does a DC assume a connection to it is trying to authenticate to the domain it manages and thus not requiring a domain to be specified? I did some additional testing, and it looks like this is specific to DCs suggesting this may be the case, but I'm not sure that I'm articulating this correctly. To test, I connected to an RDS server that is not a DC but is subject to one's policies, and a correct domain was required.

Has anyone else ever experienced this, or have any tips to point me in the right direction?

Thank you for your time.